# How to add a SwitchParameter to an attribute collection?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have an attribute collection defined like so:

```
$AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
```

While I am able to add attributes and validateset options I am however unable to add a SwitchParameter to the collection.

```
$SwitchParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter 
$AttributeCollection.Add($SwitchParameter)
```

When I run the above I get the following error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".

Since the attribute collection takes a parameter of type `System.Attribute` I guess there must be a different way of adding the SwitchParameter, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Why do you want to add `SwitchParameter` to attribute collection? Are you defining dynamic parameter? In that case, you does not need any special attribute for switch parameter. `SwitchParameter` is parameter type not attribute.

Comment: Spot on 'PeterAl'...i am trying to add a dynamic parameter :). so if i dont have to use attributes then how do i make the switch parameter part of a parameterset.Also i suppose then i dont have to use the 'runtimedefinedparameter constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not have to use any additional attributes to make parameter to be switch parameter. You just declare it's type as `System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter` or `switch`.

```powershell
function f{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string[]]$Names
    )
    dynamicparam{
        $DynamicParams=New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        foreach($Name in $Names){
            $Attributes=@(
                New-Object Parameter -Property @{ParameterSetName="Set_$Name"}
            )
            $Param=New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter $Name,switch,$Attributes
            $DynamicParams.Add($Name,$Param)
        }
        $DynamicParams
    }
}
```

Comment: ah so use 'switch' as a .NET type... yeah now why didn't i think of that :)...anyways that worked, thanks again 'PetSerAI'